# What are my options for a mix of vm-like features and container-like speed?

Tags: virtual-machine

I want to create *"something in between a VM and a container"*, because:

- A regular VM is slow
- A container doesn't emulate a system well enough

More specific:

- What I certainly want to avoid:

  - Virtualized hardware *(too heavy)*
- What I certainly need:

  - The ability to control the resources, more specifically: memory, disk and cpu
  - A `/proc` that acts extremely similar to a "real" one *(e.g. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq ; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` should trigger a reboot)*
  - Good isolation from the host *(e.g. the previous command should **not** reboot the host)*
  - Ability to run a lightweight Linux distro
- What I don't need but I don't mind having:

  - The ability to use X11 without enforcing it
- What I would like but could also live without:

  - A virtualized kernel

What technologies would fit my needs ?

Comment: You can assign hardware to a VM so hardware interfaces are just passed through.  But most of them visualize the video.

Comment: That is **extremely** interesting and sounds a lot like what I want ! But... will it keep working when you have multiple VM's ? (If the OS on each VM thinks that hardware only belongs to him, I assume you will end up in problems)

Comment: It would seem that you would want a KVM based solution. VMware vSphere, Proxmox, (both are virtualisation OSs), and self-setup KVM are examples. They essentially passthrough hardware without much config from your end. (I hope this does not fall into your definition of "virtualised hardware")

Comment: That's why you have to assign the hardware to the VM -- then other VMs can't use it.  For example, some (server grade) network card hardware directly support virtualization, and you can split the card into multiple virtual interfaces implemented in hardware, with each one assigned to a different VM.

Comment: Could I also ask if there is a reason why open-vm-tools, VBoxGuestAdditions, or VMwareTools doesn't do the trick for you? Personally for day to day virtualisation the paravirtualisation capabilities of VMwareTools seems to be sufficient

Comment: @user10489 Hm... I guess, on a regular desktop, this would be trivial for memory but hard for cpu (if you have a low amount of cores and a large amount of vm's)

Comment: @Timothy Wong Once you have 4 or more VM's it becomes really slow. I am blaming this on hardware virtualization (but I could be wrong)

Comment: 4 (lightweight) VMs aren't a lot for a decently specced computer. You need to keep in mind that spinning up VMs doesn't allocate physical resources, but merely shares them. It will be difficult to workaround this by just installing a piece of software. You'll probably want to look into KVMs (even then things like network bandwidth will be shared)

Comment: Assigning hardware to a VM only removes emulation layer overhead, it doesn't change that limited resources like bus bandwidth and network bandwidth are still being shared.  It is possible but not particularly helpful to assign cpu and memory to a VM -- it is better to just not over allocate those.

Comment: That was the first example I could think off, but a bind mount wouldn't work. It would not kill the container/vm

Comment: It would just write a '1' in that first file and a 'b' into that 2nd file, nothing else would happen. The container will not act upon it (as should be the case)

Comment: This sounds a lot like Kata containers: https://katacontainers.io/

Comment: @HenriMenke According to [this](https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers/blob/main/docs/hypervisors.md#types), kata containers is just a framework which runs atop other hypervisors; from that list of 4, 3 are based on kvm, and 1 runs on bare metal. I would not argue about the added value of that framework (I haven't used it), but how could that be any faster or lighter than running those vm hypervisors directly?